# How do I use mpack to send an HTML file as an attachment to an email from the command line?

Tags: bash, email

I'm using `mpack` to automate sending emails, but when I try to attach an HTML file it gets incorporated into the body of the email, rather than added as an attachment. Is there a way around this?

```
mpack -s "Big Report" -d message-body.txt the_report.html person@gmail.com
```

This produces an email where `message-body.txt` is concatenated with the contents of the HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mpack` is a very obscure program. As far as I can see from its manpage, it cannot handle attachments. Maybe you should consider something else, say `mailx` or `mutt`. Both handle attachments with the option `-a`.